# How to retrieve data from file using login code and splitting method

Tags: python

The problem is that I can't retrieve data from the file after entering that information in function register. The second problem is that I want to first display the function `login`, then if the user is not registered it will display function `register`.

```
def register():
    global username
    global password
    global login
    username = str(input("Please Enter your name:      "))
    password = str(input("Please Enter your password:      "))
    login=open("login.txt","a")
    username=username + "\n"
    login.write(username)
    login.write(password)
    login.close()
    register()

def login():
    user1= str(input("Please Enter your name:      "))
    pass1= str(input("Please Enter your password:      "))
    open('login.txt',"r")
    for line in login.readlines():
        search = line.split()
        if user1 == search[0] & pass1 == search [1]:
            print ("Accessed")
        else:
            print ("Please Register ")
            register()
```

Comment: So, you have function called `login` and a global variable called `login`? Why do you do that?

Comment: im rly confused about what should i do, first mistake is in login. for this part should i delete global variable login?

Comment: and also what prevents me to retrieve the data from the file after i already entered the information